# how to add new marker after map loaded with socket.io in android studio

Tags: java, android, socket.io

im using Google map api for android studio, and im trying to add new marker  when my socket.io get new location from server.
meaning  after map loaded , i want to write socket.on("newloc",...)... and set new marker on my map, but its giving force close.
my code :

```
    socket.on("miad", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {

            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(newlat,newlng);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("First Pit Stop")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        }
    });
```

this is short of my code and for example i get newlat and newlng from socket.

Comment: Is the 'call(Object...args)' class on the main thread? I assume that wrapping the mMap.addMarker() method inside the runOnUiThread(Runnable); might do the trick.

Comment: @March3April4 i write my socket code in OnMapReady()  is it ok?

Comment: The suspicious part is whether your call method is in the main thread or not. Try wrapping it with the runOnUiThread. If that doesnt work, post your error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's happening inside your socket object.

As I suggested at the comment, try this.

```
private void onMapReady(GoogleMap map){

 try {

        socket.on("miad", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {

                try {

                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(newlat, newlng);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title("First Pit Stop")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                     .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("runOnUiThread", "Ex", e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("onMapReady", "Ex", e);
    }
}
```

At least it will tell you in your logcat which line is breaking your code and perphaps why it is.